# How to update a Deployment via editing yml file

Tags: kubernetes

The official [kubernetes guidelines](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), instructs on updating the deployment either by performing a command line `set`:

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
```

or by inline editing (that will launch the default editor I guess)

```
kubectl edit deployment/nginx-deployment
```

However both processes make consistency more difficult given that one needs to go and udpate offline the `my-deployment.yml` file, where the up & running deployment came from. (and this deprives one from the advantage of keeping their manifests version-controlled).

Is there a way to

- launch a deployment via the file
- perform (when needed) updates to the **same** file
- update the deployment by pointing to the same, updated file?

Comment: What about `kubectl apply`, see also [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-apply)?

Comment: When I issue `kubectl apply -f <filename>` I get a warning that it should not be used for resources previously created via `kubectl create -f <filename>`. The docs on the differences between imperative / declarative commands confuse me a bit to be honest.

Comment: Hmm, did you read the docs I linked to? Especially the part where it says `Note: To use apply, always create resource initially with either kubectl apply or kubectl create --save-config`?

Comment: Thanks I was missing that part ... I will try this approach when (re)creating my resources in case it helps me avoid similar warnings

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it simply by following steps -

1. Edit the deployment.yaml file
2. Run below command -

   ```
   kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
   ```

This is what I usually follow. You can use a kubectl patch or edit also.

Comment: This actually wont work unless you delete the old deployment.

Comment: It should work fine. This will override the existing deployment in case of old deployment is present.

Comment: `kubectl apply --filename deployment.yaml --namespace DEP_NAMESPACE` is the way to go but make sure to update the `spec.containers.image` to new image.

Comment: This works but old pods, replicasets etc everything is there, you need to manually clear everything

Comment: this command simply works. no need to manually delete old deployments.

Comment: Does this still provide rollback support