# How do I update a deployment via YAML with rollback support?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to update a deployment via the YAML file, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191853/how-to-update-a-deployment-via-editing-yml-file). I have the following yaml file...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: simple-server-deployment
  labels:
    app: simple-server
spec: 
  replicas: 3
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: simple-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simple-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: simple-server
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
```

I tried changing the code by changing `replicas: 3` to `replicas: 1`. Next I redeployed like `kubectl apply -f simple-deployment.yml` and I get `deployment.apps/simple-server-deployment configured`. However, when I run `kubectl rollout history deployment/simple-server-deployment` I only see 1 entry...

```
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
```

How do I do the same thing while increasing the revision so it is possible to rollback?

*I know this can be done without the YAML but this is just an example case. In the real world I will have far more changes and need to use the YAML.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`--record` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875309/what-does-record-do-in-kubernetes-deployment) so in your case the command will look like:

```
kubectl apply -f simple-deployment.yml --record
```

However, a few notes.

First,  [`--record` flag is deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40422) - you will see following message when you will run `kubectl apply` with the `--record` flag:

```
Flag --record has been deprecated, --record will be removed in the future
```

However, [there is no replacement for this flag yet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40422#issuecomment-995371023), but keep in mind that in the future there probably will be.

Second thing, not every change will be recorded (even with `--record` flag) - I tested your example from the main question and there is no new revision. Why? [It's because:](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23989#issuecomment-207226153):

> [@deech](https://github.com/deech) this is expected behavior. The `Deployment` only create a new revision (i.e. another `Replica Set`) when you update its pod template. Scaling it won't create another revision.

Considering the two above, you need to think (and probably test) if the `--record` flag is suitable for you. Maybe it's better to use some [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) like [git](https://git-scm.com/), but as I said, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: Well put thank you for all of the context. I think I am going to hold off on accepting though till we have a non-deprecated answer but I can be swayed. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to manually declare the Change Cause when you use this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not heard of such a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Change of replicas does not create new history record. You can add `--record` to you `apply` command and check the annotation later to see what was the last spec applied.